# numpy shadowing builtin function : what is the fully qualified name for built in function?

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

I use IPython which opens numpy automatically, as far as I understand.

This redefines the builtin function 'sum' which I'd like to access.

How can I get a hold on it ?

ps : I think I got it :

```
import __builtin__ as base

base.sum
```

from [tfm](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html#module-__builtin__)

Comment: Your comment on ipython and numpy sparked my interest. Which version of ipython do you use and why do you think it imports numpy automatically?
And how come numpy.sum would overwrite the builtin sum?
When I open ipython and import numpy manually, I need to call numpy.sum for the numpy sum and sum for the built in sum.
Did you modify your ipython config file to execute "from numpy import *"? That would overwrite the built in sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `--pylab` or equivalent import numpy in global namespace (as well as other stuff) you should set `import_all` to false if you don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did something to your `ipython` config.

```
IPython 0.13.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
<snip>

In [1]: sum?
Type:       builtin_function_or_method
String Form:<built-in function sum>
Namespace:  Python builtin
```